# Any way to set interface to promiscuous in 18.04 using netplan?

Tags: 18.04, netplan

I'm honestly a bit stunned that this isn't covered. It's not that unusual, and it's simply not at all covered in the man pages for netplan. Any idea how to set an interface to promiscuous using netplan?

Comment: I actually found a developer that was kind enough to respond to me, so I can answer definitively that this is not currently possible. Hopefully it will be in the future as netplan seems to be a superior way to manage network interfaces. Also, this thread mentions a workaround but there is currently a bug that causes it to fail. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037223/ubuntu-17-10-openvpn-tap-help/1037955#1037955